# Can I create a rule that triggers on a query with a time delta?

Tags: aws-iot

For example my device reports on two on/off states: a and b.  The device reports state 3 times per second.

Is it possible to create a rule in iot core that will trigger if a and b are switched on within 1 second of each other?

Or is the proper approach to save state history and trigger a lambda that will query recent state from DynamoDB for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS IoT rules are stateless so either the payload needs to have the necessary information or (as you suggest) the rule action (e.g. a lambda) would need to have some persistent storage to determine this.